# ConEmu -runlist Commands

Tags: conemu

EDIT: I now realize my problem is specific to attempting to use a working variant of this command inside a ConEmu64.exe sub-tab cmd.exe, so if anyone can show me a successful execution of this command in that manner, I would be most grateful.

TL/DR: Can someone please show me a proper example of how to get -runlist functional?

Supposedly the [following command](https://conemu.github.io/en/ConEmuArgs.html):

```
ConEmu.exe -runlist cmd -cur_console:fn ||| cmd -cur_console:s1TVn ||| cmd -cur_console:s1THn ||| cmd -cur_console:s2THn
```

is able to be executed in a ConEmu `cmd.exe` box. I have copied and pasted this command directly to educate myself. When I attempt to use this command I get the following:

```
| was unexpected at this time.
```

I find it strange they use deprecated commands in their examples and I have not been able to find anything on the internet showing use of `-runlist` anywhere. Can someone please show me a proper example of how to get `-runlist` functional?

[image: ConEmu Website Example Command]

Comment: The docs state examples for both Win+R and cmd.exe prompt. So why your question arrears? What is unclear?

Answer (score 1):

> When I attempt to use this command [...] I get the following: `| was unexpected at this time.`

Windows often parses things differently in different contexts (e.g. command line, batch file, run dialog, shortcuts). This particular notation (`|||`) doesn't parse correctly at the command line.

> I find it strange they use deprecated commands in their examples and I have not been able to find anything on the internet showing use of `-runlist` anywhere.

As noted in the comments below, `-runlist` is a current command.

Also, I believe ConEmu is still essentially a one-person project (i.e. smallish), so a lack of examples outside the official documentation wouldn't seem surprising to me (though the author does [answer questions here](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/conemu)).

> Can someone please show me a proper example of how to get `-runlist` functional?

From the [official documentation](https://conemu.github.io/en/ConEmuArgs.html):

- *Example 3* - <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (Windows `Run` dialog)

  ```
  ConEmu -runlist cmd -cur_console:fn ||| cmd -cur_console:s1TVn ||| cmd -cur_console:s1THn ||| cmd -cur_console:s2THn
  ```
- *Example 3* - Windows Shortcut (Target)

  ```
  ConEmu -runlist cmd -cur_console:fn ||| cmd -cur_console:s1TVn ||| cmd -cur_console:s1THn ||| cmd -cur_console:s2THn
  ```
- *`-runlist commands`* - Windows Batch File (or CMD Window)

  ```
  ConEmu -runlist cmd -cur_console:fn ^|^|^| cmd -cur_console:s1TVn ^|^|^| cmd -cur_console:s1THn ^|^|^| cmd -cur_console:s2THn
  ```
- *Example 5 (modified)* - Windows Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`)

  ```
  start "" "ConEmu" -runlist cmd -cur_console:fn ^|^|^| cmd -cur_console:s1TVn ^|^|^| cmd -cur_console:s1THn ^|^|^| -cur_console:s2THn
  ```

Note that Example 5 is also apparently meant to be used in batch files. In practice, however, calling `ConEmu` directly in a batch file (rather than using Windows [start](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)) worked for me, at least with the example command given. Your experiences may vary.

It is also likely worth mentioning that `|||` isn't treated any differently by ConEmu than in it is in a normal CMD window. So you will still need to use e.g. the third and fourth examples (with escaped `|` [i.e. `^|`], above) if you wish to spawn a new ConEmu window split into four CMD windows from ConEmu itself.

*ex. Escaped Pipes in ConEmu*

[image]

*ex. Escaped Pipes (Result)*

[image]

Comment: Why do you say "deprecated command"? The `-runlist` is actual and noted in the docs.

Comment: @Maximus I was merely reflecting the statement made by OP in the original question. I suspected that statement was incorrect but thank you for clarifying. =) I have updated my answer .

Comment: @Anaksunaman I am able to get the commands to run in WIN+R and an actual Windows cmd.exe, but I am confounded as to why I cannot run them from a cmd.exe inside of an already established conemu cmd.exe window. I still run into the exact same "expected |" problem.\
\
Can you show me a workable version of this command that you are able to execute INSIDE a ConEmu window's cmd.exe box?

Comment: @Spade86 Hmm. Perhaps I misunderstood something. Are you trying to split an *existing* ConEmu window into 4 sub-windows?

Comment: @Spade86 If not, then there should be no reason (as far as I am aware) that running Examples 3 and 4 above from an existing ConEmu CMD window shouldn't produce a new ConEmu window with four new CMD terminals, as expected. The `|||` syntax isn't treated special or differently in ConEmu itself.